# Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: javascript, css, angular, image, bootstrap-4

when run the angular application which contain home component, an error shows that refused to apply styles and images are not found , I don't know why, because the CSS and image folder is in the /src/assets folder

I tried to update angular.json file and check the path also , and upgrade the NPM version

> [**this is the error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojY7l.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add `<base href="/">` in `public/index.html`.

Comment: already added to index.html